# Working out the orientation of a target to a rotating sprite

Tags: xna, rotation, directions

I've got a player sprite that moves by rotation and its rotation is constantly changing but I also need to work out if a target is to the left or right of it and not within 45 degrees of the front or rear rotation.

I've written this code which I think should work but it seems only occasional pick up one side and slightly more on the other.

```
        public void GrappleCheck(AsteroidSprite target)
    {
        float targetTragectory = (float)Math.Atan2(Position.Y - target.Position.Y, Position.X - target.Position.X);

        if (targetTragectory < 0)
            targetTragectory += (float)(Math.PI * 2);

        if (Rotation < 0)
            Rotation += (float)(Math.PI * 2);

        if ((targetTragectory > Rotation + (float)(MathHelper.PiOver4 / 2)) && (targetTragectory < Rotation + (float)(Math.PI - (MathHelper.PiOver4 / 2))))
        {
            target.Distance = Vector2.Distance(Position, target.Position);
            if (RightTarget != null)
            {
                if (RightTarget.Distance > target.Distance)
                {
                    RightTarget.isTarget = false;
                    RightTarget = target;
                    RightTarget.ColorTint = Color.Blue;
                    RightTarget.isTarget = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RightTarget = target;
                RightTarget.ColorTint = Color.Blue;
                RightTarget.isTarget = true;
            }
        }
        else if ((targetTragectory < Rotation - (float)(MathHelper.PiOver4 / 2)) && (targetTragectory > Rotation - (float)(Math.PI - (MathHelper.PiOver4 / 2))))
        {
            target.Distance = Vector2.Distance(Position, target.Position);
            if (LeftTarget != null)
            {
                if (LeftTarget.Distance > target.Distance)
                {
                    LeftTarget.isTarget = false;
                    LeftTarget = target;
                    LeftTarget.ColorTint = Color.Red;
                    LeftTarget.isTarget = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LeftTarget = target;
                LeftTarget.ColorTint = Color.Red;
                LeftTarget.isTarget = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            target.isTarget = false;
        }

        if (controlInput.IsHeld(Keys.X))
        {
            Speed = Speed;
        }
```

Comment: I've worked out the problem, my player is rotation 0 - 2*PI where as the "targetTragectory" rotates (clockwise) 0 - PI then -PI - 0, not worked out how to resolve this yet though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved it, the player rotation can be from 0 to 2 x PI + or -, to keep it + though I put in

```
if (Rotation < 0)
    Rotation += (float)Math.PI * 2;
```

the rotation to the target can be 0-PI or 0 - Negative PI depending on the way you declare the atan2 and where the player is.

```
//This works out the difference from the targets rotation to the players rotation.

RotationDif = TargetRotation - PlayerRotation;

//If the difference is greater than PI then when we check to see if its is within
//the range 0-PI or 0-Negative PI it will be missed whilst still possibly being on 
//either side of the player, adding PI * 2 to the targets rotation basically spins
//it past the player so the Difference will be the shortest angle.

if(Math.Abs(RotationDif) > Math.PI)
   RotationDif = TargetRotation + (float)(Math.PI * 2) - PlayerRotation;

//Next we check to see if the target is left(negative) or
//the right(positive), the negative/positive assignment will depend
//on which way round you did the atan2 to get the target rotation.

if ((RotationDif > 0) && (RotationDif < (float)Math.PI))

    //Insert right target code here

else if ((RotationDif < 0) && (RotationDif > -(float)Math.PI))

    //Insert left target code here

else

    //Insert no target code here to cover all basis
```

And that's it, I've made the If (RotationDif > 0) etc differently so the a 45 degree angle front and back is ignored by making it

```
If ((RotationDif > (float)(Math.PI / 8) &&
    (RotationDif < (float)(Math.PI - (Math.PI / 8)))
```

and the opposite for the other side, hope this helps someone else as it took me nearly 2 sodding weeks to work out :/

Answer (score 1):

Working with angles can be quite annoying. Here are some ways to solve your problems without using angles:

First, we need the direction to the target and the movement direction:

```
var targetDirection = target.Positon - Position;
// Update this to match the actual direction. The following line assumes that
// a rotation of 0 results in the right direction.
var movementDirection = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(Rotation), (float)Math.Sin(Rotation));
```

The first problem you want to solve is determining, if the target is within a 45° cone. You can calculate the actual angle with the following formula:

```
var dot = Vector2.Dot(myDirection, targetDirection);
//if dot is negative, then target is behind me, so just use the absolute value
var cos = Math.Abs(dot) / myDirection.Length() / targetDirection.Length();
var angle = Math.Acos(cos);
if(angle < MathHelper.PiOver4 / 2) //45° opening angle
    ; // within cone
else
    ; // outside cone
```

Your second problem is determining, if the target is on the left or right side. We use a vector that is ortogonal to `myDirection` and points to the left for this:

```
//assuming that +x is the right axis and +y is the down axis
var normal = new Vector2(myDirection.Y, -myDirection.X);
dot = Vector2.Dot(normal, targetDirection);
if(dot > 0)
    ; // target is on the left side
else
    ; // target is on the right side
```

I hope that makes cleaning up your code a bit easier and more comprehensible. You should consider extracting some code in separate methods to make it more readable.